# Using JavaScript in a panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm making a Firefox add-on using the Add-on SDK. I can't find a way to use JavaScript code in a panel. Here is what I've done:

```
//file main.js
data = require("self").data

var MeteoPanel = require("panel").Panel({
  width:740,
  height:350,
  contentURL: data.url("test.html"), 
  allow:true
});

require("widget").Widget({
  id: "open-meteo-btn",
  label: "Meteo",
  contentURL: data.url("icon.png"),
  panel: MeteoPanel
});
```

This works but I can't use JavaScript in the `test.html` page.
Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the js in a separate file, and then:

```
var MeteoPanel = require("panel").Panel({
  width:740,
  height:350,
  contentURL: data.url("test.html"), 
  contentScriptFile: data.url("yourJSFile.js"), //Add this line
  allow:true
});
```

Seems like `contentScriptFile` accepts an array too, so you could change its value to `[data.url("file1.js"),data.url("file2.js")]` if you need for instance to add 2 source files.

Comment: i've tried that before but i does not work. I've tried also to put my js file in the LIB and in the DATA folder. But nothing seems to work :)

Comment: Check the `reddit-panel` example. It includes `jquery` and a source file. Seems like everything that's javascript must be outside the html. Also put the js files in the `data` dir.

Comment: Thx, the example was very usefull !

Comment: Great! What was the info you missed ?